# ui-select dropdown z-index with overflow: auto

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, angular-ui-select

I've found a lot of questions about the subject but none address my issue.

I'm using ui-select on a bootstrap modal

I need to use `overflow-y:auto;` but that is showing the modal behind the element of course because there is overflow

Like this example http://plnkr.co/edit/g7xH3yajVxttvnuK3UAR?p=preview

Is there a way to maintain the overflow and make the dropdown appear on top?

There was a solution with `position fixed` but it look odd sometimes

Comment: What happens when you take out `overflow: auto` off `<div class='panel-body'>`?

Comment: Check the updated plunker. I need the overflow because the modal body has a fixed height and there are other elements pushing the select below or appearing below it. and they should not overflow.

Comment: Does `.panel-body' need to have a fixed height?

Comment: Yes it is a requirement.

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what you're looking to do. Your panel body has a fixed height. Are you looking to hide things that go outside of that? Or are you trying to have that dropdown show up above other elements in the body? Your question kind of hints at both?

Comment: It's a general example, I have a modal and the ui-select is inside the modal body, we want the modal to be with a fixed height, but keeping an overflow auto because some content is dynamic.